# Interleave two vectors

Tags: vectorization, sse, simd, intrinsics, avx

I'm trying my first steps with SIMD and I was wondering what the right approach is to the following problem. Consider two vectors:

```
+---+---+---+---+    +---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |    | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
+---+---+---+---+    +---+---+---+---+
```

How to "interleave" the elements of those vectors so that they become:

```
+---+---+---+---+    +---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 4 | 1 | 5 |    | 2 | 6 | 3 | 7 |
+---+---+---+---+    +---+---+---+---+
```

I was surprised I could not find an instruction for doing it, given the great many kinds of shuffles, broadcasts, permutes, ... Probably it could be done with some `unpacklo` and `unpackhi` and what not, but I was wondering if there is a canonical way of doing it as it seems to be quite common problem (SoA vs. AoS). For simplicity let's assume AVX(2) and vectors of four floats.

Edit:

Floats vs. doubles

The comment below (correctly) suggest I should use `unpcklps` and `unpckhps` for floats. Which instruction should I use to unpack vector of four doubles? I'm asking because `_mm256_unpacklo_pd`/`_mm256_unpackhi_pd`:

> Unpack and interleave double-precision (64-bit) floating-point elements from the high half of each 128-bit lane in a and b, and store the results in dst.

```
DEFINE INTERLEAVE_HIGH_QWORDS(src1[127:0], src2[127:0]) {
    dst[63:0] := src1[127:64] 
    dst[127:64] := src2[127:64] 
    RETURN dst[127:0]   
}
dst[127:0] := INTERLEAVE_HIGH_QWORDS(a[127:0], b[127:0])
dst[255:128] := INTERLEAVE_HIGH_QWORDS(a[255:128], b[255:128])
dst[MAX:256] := 0
```

So what it apparently does is:

```
+---+---+---+---+    +---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 4 | 2 | 6 |    | 1 | 5 | 3 | 7 |
+---+---+---+---+    +---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: `unpcklps` and `unpckhps` instructions do exactly what you want. See also my article about the subject http://const.me/articles/simd/simd.pdf float shuffles are on page 11, integer shuffles on page 16.

Comment: If I wanted to unpack doubles, instead of floats, which instruction should I use? Apparently `_mm256_unpacklo_pd` "interleave[s] ... elements from the low half of each 128-bit lane".

Comment: Right, 256-bit AVX shuffles are "in-lane", like two separate 128-bit `unpcklpd` operations in each lane of the __m256[i/d] vector.  So you'd probably want `vinsertf128` (for low halves) or `vperm2f128` (for high halves) to get the data you want into a single vector + `vpermpd` to reorder it within that vector.  It's not until AVX-512 that Intel introduced proper 2-vector lane-crossing shuffles like `vpermt2pd` that avoid this level of suckage.  However, sometimes instead of 2 shuffles per vector output, you can do some shuffle and some blend, improving throughput.

Comment: @PeterCordes I know I'm just at the beginning of this whole SIMD thing so I don't understand most of the stuff but "this level of suckage" occurred to me more than once.  I see that those instruction you mention have higher latency than `unpcklps`/`unpckhps`, do you recommend any particular sequence of instructions so that it does not hurt too much (to emulate `vpermt2pd` or similar)?

Comment: Usually throughput matters more than latency, thanks to out-of-order exec being able to overlap independent iterations.  But Intel CPUs (from Haswell until Ice Lake) only have   1/clock shuffle throughput so it's usually just total number of shuffles you want to minimize.  Unless there's something clever that allows one or two vblendpd instead of one of the 4 shuffles, probably just what I suggested.

Comment: Maybe lane-swap one input with `vperm2f128`, then blend 2 different ways to create `0 1 | 4 5` and `6 7 | 2 3`, then 2x `vpermpd` to shuffle the data into place.  That avoids needing any vector constants, which is nice, and costs 2 cheap blends + 3 shuffles, vs. 4 shuffles.  So it's worse for front-end throughput, better for back-end port 5 pressure.  IDK if there's an existing Q&A showing any more clever trick.

Comment: Interleaving pairs of 8x float vectors (`__m256`) might use a similar combo of shuffle and blend.

Comment: For 256 bit vectors you can also consider to `vextractf128` or `vinsertf128` directly to or from memory (before/after `unpck[lh]p[sf]`) which does not cause any shuffle operation, but requires more stores or loads (really depends on what you want to do overall).

Comment: For questions like this, generally the best place to start is by [asking the compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/6fsx9Y).  `__builtin_shufllevector` (clang) and `__builtin_shuffle` (GCC) tend to be really good at this.

Comment: What does a straight C or Fortran loop compile to in terms of the instructions?
Whatever that optimises to may provide an interesting comparison.